# In PHP, why does </script> not show a parse error?

Tags: php, syntax, parse-error

I was running the following [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code:

```
<?php 
    </script>
?>
```

There were no parse errors and the **output was** "`?>`" ([example](http://ideone.com/0FbOdx)).

In similar cases I do get a parse error:

```
<?php 
    </div>
?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in ...

Why doesn't `<?php </script> ?>` give the same error?

Comment: Just curious. What were trying to achieve or what was it that you were experimenting on?

Comment: Actually the case was different last night I missed the php closing tag.And after this I had a </script> tag and I spent more than 30 min to figure out why this does not have any error buts still the output is not as desire.

Comment: I don't want to live on this planet any more.

Comment: PHP does that to people.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

This must be because [there are various ways of starting a block of PHP code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

- `<? ... ?>` (known as `short_open_tag`)
- `<?php ... ?>` (the standard really)
- `<script language="php"> ... </script>` (not recommended)
- `<% ... %>` (deprecated and removed ASP-style tag after 5.3.0)

Apparently, you can open a PHP block one way, and close it the other. Didn't know that.

So in your code, you opened the block using `<?` but PHP recognizes `</script>` as the closer. What happened was:

```
<?php       <----- START PHP
</script>   <----- END PHP
?>          <----- JUST GARBAGE IN THE HTML
```

Comment: Note that using `<script language="php">` is not recommended.

Comment: Quick note, because I remembered there was some change with the `short_open_tag` directive. In PHP 5.4 `<?=` short for `<?php echo` no longer requires the `short_open_tag`. Going between systems where `<?=` was available and not available always frustrated me. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: @thatmiddleway Note that the official document recommends `<?php ... ?>` as well: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 37):

In PHP, you can use the `script` tag to open a PHP block.

So you can use

```
<script language="php">
    echo 'hello world';
</script>
```

So in your example you have mixed the normal open tag, `<?php`, with the closing tag, `</script>`. So the parser assumes that all the text after the closing script tag is normal `HTML`.

Read more in *[Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)*.